# Django string_if_invalid and default

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

I have `string_if_invalid` set to 'INVALID' in my django template settings.
And there is some template that looks like this:

```
{{ some_nonexisting_value|default:'Default value' }}
```

After rendering result looks like `'INVALID'`. So, default value is not used.
Is there any way to make `string_if_invalid` to work with default values without changing templates?

Edit:
Template settings look like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'libraries': {
                'utm_tags': 'kurator.templatetags.utm_tags',
            },
            'string_if_invalid': 'INVALID',
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'kurator.context_processors.static_hash',
                'kurator.context_processors.debug',
            ]
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Please show the template settings.

Comment: Edited question

Comment: Related: pytest has a config to throw an exception if an invalid string is in the template: https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#fail-on-template-vars-fail-for-invalid-variables-in-templates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not possible to get the `default` filter to display the provided default instead of the invalid string.

Note that [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#how-invalid-variables-are-handled) warn against using the `string_if_invalid` option:

> **For debug purposes only!**
>
> While `string_if_invalid` can be a useful debugging tool, it is a bad idea to turn it on as a ‘development default’.
>
> Many templates, including those in the Admin site, rely upon the silence of the template system when a non-existent variable is encountered. If you assign a value other than `''` to `string_if_invalid`, you will experience rendering problems with these templates and sites.
>
> Generally, `string_if_invalid` should only be enabled in order to debug a specific template problem, then cleared once debugging is complete.

For your own templates, I guess you could write your own template tag that takes the variable name and a default, then tries to fetch the variable from the template context. However, this wouldn't solve the problem in other templates that use the regular `default` filter, including the Django admin.